# Gurobi library does not load anymore [Windows]

Tags: r, windows, gurobi

As it didn't work, I reinstalled. But without success.
What do I miss?

```
install.packages('C:/gurobi800/win64/R/gurobi_8.0-0.zip', repos=NULL)
# package ‘gurobi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Sys.getenv()
# ...
# GRB_LICENSE_FILE                  C:\gurobi800\gurobi.lic
# GUROBI_HOME                       C:\gurobi800\win64
# ...
library("gurobi")
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gurobi’: package ‘gurobi’
>   was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be
>   reinstalled for use with this R version

From the **DESCRIPTION in Gurobi's R folder**:

```
Depends: slam (>= 0.1-9)
URL: http://www.gurobi.com
Built: R 3.4.0; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2018-04-21 00:42:28 UTC; windows
```

SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] slam_0.1-44

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  imsbasics_1.9.7 tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.1.19
```

Comment: What is in `C:/gurobi800/win64/R/gurobi_8.0-0.zip` -- A source package? Binaries? I'm guessing it's binaries built for an R version < 3.5.0

Comment: @duckmayr See my edit: it's a folder containing a  `gurobi/` folder. Part of the description can be found in the edit, in the `gurobi/R/` folder there `gurobi`, `gurobi.rdx` and `gurobi.rdb` files. What does that mean?

Comment: The `Built: R 3.4.0;` you see in the `DESCRIPTION` means it's a pre-built binary package, not a source package you'd have to compile. This makes installation easier and faster, **unless** you're trying to install on an incompatible R version, which is what's happened here -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll either need to go back to R 3.4.4 or get Gurobi >= 8.0.1; because a lot was changed under the hood in R moving from 3.4.4 to 3.5.0, binaries compiled for R versions < 3.5.0 will not work with R >= 3.5.0, so your Gurobi 8.0.0 will not work with your current installation of R.

Other Gurobi users have had this issue; see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gurobi/r$203.5|sort:date/gurobi/D_A81BvJupY/FI4y1TmaBgAJ), and more informatively, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gurobi/r$203.5|sort:date/gurobi/FlNcEdrY5-U/j5tgBXDCAgAJ):

> The current Gurobi release 8.0.1 ships a R package for R 3.5.X

If you'd prefer to go to an older version of R rather than a newer version of Gurobi, you can get R 3.4.4 for Windows [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.4.4/).

Comment: Is that solution obvious?

Comment: @Christoph I guess it depends on who you ask; I'd say for the typical useR, not wholly, but I'm familiar with this issue as I had a lot of headaches (re: other packages, not Gurobi) moving to 3.5.0. For package maintainers who have compiled code, this was a thing when 3.5.0 was released